# Как в QT, в QLineEdit с валидатором Double добавить возможность вводить дроби

Tags: c++, qt

у меня есть таблица ячейками которой являются виджеты QLineEdit

На них стоит валидатор double,но дробь 1/7 валидатор не пропускает

Я понимаю что можно приводить эти самые дроби в десятичные,но запись 0,142857143 не так удобна по сравнению с записью 1/7

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует использовать [QRegExpValidator Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html) c регулярным выражением, например "\d+[,|/]?\d+"